# Finding and displaying duplicates

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I have a table.  I'd like to search within this table for duplicate titles.
Lets say my data is as follows:

> title1, title2, title3, title1, title4, title2, title9

I'd like for my query to search this table and output only the duplicates.  So the output would look like:
title1
title1
title2
title2

I know how I can find the duplicates, but it only shows me one of the duplicates and not both.

```
SELECT id, title, artist_id FROM sm019_songs GROUP BY title HAVING count(title) > 1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it with a subquery.  It might make sense to load the subquery into a temp table first.  (This would work in SQL server, not sure what the exact MySql syntax would be.)

```
select id, title, artist_id
from sm019_songs
where title in
(
    SELECT title
    FROM sm019_songs
    GROUP BY title
    HAVING count(title) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what I came up with in mysql:

`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE u (title varchar(250))

TYPE=HEAP;

INSERT INTO u

SELECT title FROM t group by title having count(title) > 1;`

SELECT t.title  FROM u,t where u.title = t.title

Answer (score 0):

I'd just join the table to itself:

```
SELECT S1.*, S2.*
FROM songs S1, songs S2
WHERE S1.title = S2.title
  AND S1.id != S2.id
```

-----N